# get list of colors used in a ggplot2 plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract the fill colours from a ggplot object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774262/how-to-extract-the-fill-colours-from-a-ggplot-object)

In an arbitrary ggplot plot, say

```
p <- ggplot(data=PlantGrowth, aes(x=group, y=weight, fill=group)) + geom_boxplot()
```

is there a way to extract the code of the colors that were used (i.e. the variable named "values" that we modify with the command

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9"))
```

) ?

I would like to get the colors used in order to modify only one.

Thank you,

François

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a discrete scale (with default setting `scale_colour_hue`) the function `hue_pal` in package `scales` is used.
E.g., with three factor levels:

```
R> library(scales)
R> scales::hue_pal()(3)
[1] "#F8766D" "#00BA38" "#619CFF"
```

Comment: `hue_pal` is exported, not hidden.

Comment: thanks @hadley. I've searched for ggplot2:::hue_pal ... had to load the `scales` package, but didn't check again if it is exported or not.