# Where are the scale colours stored in a ggplot2 object?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

Say I create a plot:

```
df <- data.frame(A = 1:100, B = jitter(1:100, 25), C = c('One', 'Two'))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(A, B, colour = C)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c('red', 'green'))
```

Where are those colours (red and green) stored in `p`?

---

I can see the palette of functions being used in a function here:

```
p$scales$scales[[1]]$palette
```

The contents of this function are:

```
function (n) 
{
  if (n > length(values)) {
    stop("Insufficient values in manual scale. ", n, " needed but only ", 
      length(values), " provided.", call. = FALSE)
  }
  values
}
```

I think the colours must be stored in `values` there but I have no idea where they actually are in `p`.

---

P.s. I've seen this question: [How to extract the fill colours from a ggplot object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774262/how-to-extract-the-fill-colours-from-a-ggplot-object). But for what I'm trying to do I can't build the plot. I need to get at the colours before it's built.

If there was some way of recursively searching `p` for the characters "red" or "green" that would probably help find these values.

---

EDIT: What I'm ultimately trying to do.

I'm trying to edit plots before they are plotted. The idea being that given some plot `p` you can just do something like this:

```
apply_theme(p)
```

...and a colour scheme is applied to the entire plot (including scales, gradients etc.). This is to avoid having to do things like:

```
p + some_theme + scales_colour_manual(values = plot_theme)
```

I'm trying to reduce effort by the user so that they can just apply a theme to an entire plot and not have to worry about whether they are colouring a gradient, discrete scale or whatever.

Building the plot is a partial solution. But I would like to able to apply the theme and still be able to edit the plot later.

I've been able to edit `p` so that whatever colours are applied to geoms retrospectively. But I just can't find how to do that with scale colours. I know the colours must be in there somewhere!

Comment: Sorry, I just saw that you can't build the plot. Thus, I deleted my answer. Can you explain why building the plot is not an option?

Comment: @Roland added an edit. Maybe I'm going about this entirely the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

Not much progress, but I've ruled out a few places that it might be hiding.

You can see all the character vector that `p` contains with

```
Filter(is.character, unlist(p))
# $labels.x
# [1] "A"

# $labels.y
# [1] "B"

# $labels.colour
# [1] "C"
```

So it isn't stored directly.

By setting `options(error = recover)` and then forcing an error by only providing one colour, we can inspect the call stack.

```
(p <- ggplot(df, aes(A, B, colour = C)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = 'red')
)

 1: print(list(data = list(A = 1:100, B = c(4.32692646654323, 3.46481398493052, 0.4989527114667, 
...
13: scale$palette(n)
```

Entering frame `13: scale$palette(n)`, we can see that the variable `values` does indeed store the colour information.

```
Browse[1]> values
[1] "red"
```

We can hunt through each frame in the call stack, but something odd is happening - it doesn't appear to be anywhere.

```
Browse[1]> sapply(
  sys.frames(), 
  function(envir) 
  {
    exists("values", envir, inherits = FALSE)
  }
)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[16] FALSE FALSE
```

(See `sys.status()` for the full details of the call stack.)

I suspect that some odd evaluation technique is being used with the `Scales` reference class.

Comment: +1 thanks for the effort. Part of the difficulty comes from the amount of nesting going on in `p`. E.g. `Filter(is.character, unlist(p))` only returns three characters... but I know for a fact there are more (Try: `Filter(is.character, unlist(p$scales$scales))` just as an example). `values` might not exist in `p`... the colours may be under some other name. I probably need some method to completely `unlist()` `p`.

Answer (score 0):

```
g <- ggplot_build(p)
data.frame(colours = unique(g$data[[1]]["colour"]),
             label = g$plot$scales$scales[[1]]$get_labels())
```

Your will see the color - legend data.frame here:

[image]