# Retrieve Colour - Value Mapping From ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I assume the ggplot scales creates some sort of function which reads the appropriate `aes` value and returns the `colour`, `size`, etc. Can this be used as a standalone function?

For example, to this function I will pass the necessary arguments (`range`, `limits`, `high`, `low`, etc.) and a value which I want to get the mapping for, and the output of the function will be the `colour` / `size` / etc.

```
# example of usage
HypotheticalScaleFunction(
   range = c(0,10),
   high = '#000000',
   low = '#222222',
   ValueToLookup = 5
)
# this should return -
"#111111"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774262/how-to-extract-the-fill-colours-from-a-ggplot-object/11774500#11774500

Comment: Not really. If I have applied a continuous fill and I want to query for a value that wasn't there in the original dataset, then this won't work.

Comment: OK, sorry, I misunderstood your question. You might wish to elaborate and provide a minimal example.

Comment: No problems, my textual description probably wasn't clear. I've added an example now.

Comment: What's the reason you want to do this manually?

Comment: I like ggplot's colours but I need to send the data and plot it somewhere else where I don't have ggplot available to me. If I can send the colour values as data then I can recreate a very similar look at the other end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this by reading through the source, by typing in scale functions. For example, if you read through the source for `ggplot2::scale_color_continuous`, you will find that it uses `seq_gradient_pal` from the `scales` package.

So, for color on a continious scale, we can define the following function (with the defaults that `ggplot` uses):

```
ColorScaleFunction <- function(Range, high = "#56B1F7", low = "#132B43", ValueToLookup) {
  seq_gradient_pal(low, high)((ValueToLookup - Range[1]) / diff(Range))
}
```

This results in the typical dark blue colors that you get by default, in heatmaps for example.

It produces `#161616` on your example though.