# Extract annotation from ggplot2 object

Tags: r, ggplot2

To write a test unit that checks the presence of a specific annotation on a ggplot2 figure, I need to extract the annotation text from the ggplot2 object. This [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927027/how-to-extract-the-legend-labels-from-a-ggplot2-object) does the job for legend labels, but annotations seem to be buried deeper in the structure. An example ggplot2 object could be this:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars[c(1,15),], aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + geom_point()
p + annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = "Some text")
```

I have tried dput() and str(), without success.

```
dput(p)
structure(list(data = structure(list(mpg = c(21, 10.4), cyl = c(6, 
8), disp = c(160, 472), hp = c(110, 205), drat = c(3.9, 2.93), 
    wt = c(2.62, 5.25), qsec = c(16.46, 17.98), vs = c(0, 0), 
    am = c(1, 0), gear = c(4, 3), carb = c(4, 4)), row.names = c("Mazda RX4", 
"Cadillac Fleetwood"), class = "data.frame"), layers = list(<environment>), 
    scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(x = ~wt, 
        y = ~mpg), class = "uneval"), theme = list(), coordinates = <environment>, 
    facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>, labels = list(
        x = "wt", y = "mpg")), class = c("gg", "ggplot"))
str(p)
List of 9
 $ data       :'data.frame':    2 obs. of  11 variables:
  ..$ mpg : num [1:2] 21 10.4
  ..$ cyl : num [1:2] 6 8
  ..$ disp: num [1:2] 160 472
  ..$ hp  : num [1:2] 110 205
  ..$ drat: num [1:2] 3.9 2.93
  ..$ wt  : num [1:2] 2.62 5.25
  ..$ qsec: num [1:2] 16.5 18
  ..$ vs  : num [1:2] 0 0
  ..$ am  : num [1:2] 1 0
  ..$ gear: num [1:2] 4 3
  ..$ carb: num [1:2] 4 4
 $ layers     :List of 1
  ..$ :Classes 'LayerInstance', 'Layer', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class LayerInstance, Layer, gg>
    aes_params: list
    compute_aesthetics: function
    compute_geom_1: function
    compute_geom_2: function
    compute_position: function
    compute_statistic: function
    computed_geom_params: list
    computed_mapping: uneval
    computed_stat_params: list
    constructor: call
    data: waiver
    draw_geom: function
    finish_statistics: function
    geom: <ggproto object: Class GeomPoint, Geom, gg>
        aesthetics: function
        default_aes: uneval
        draw_group: function
        draw_key: function
        draw_layer: function
        draw_panel: function
        extra_params: na.rm
        handle_na: function
        non_missing_aes: size shape colour
        optional_aes: 
        parameters: function
        rename_size: FALSE
        required_aes: x y
        setup_data: function
        setup_params: function
        use_defaults: function
        super:  <ggproto object: Class Geom, gg>
    geom_params: list
    inherit.aes: TRUE
    layer_data: function
    map_statistic: function
    mapping: NULL
    position: <ggproto object: Class PositionIdentity, Position, gg>
        compute_layer: function
        compute_panel: function
        required_aes: 
        setup_data: function
        setup_params: function
        super:  <ggproto object: Class Position, gg>
    print: function
    setup_layer: function
    show.legend: NA
    stat: <ggproto object: Class StatIdentity, Stat, gg>
        aesthetics: function
        compute_group: function
        compute_layer: function
        compute_panel: function
        default_aes: uneval
        dropped_aes: 
        extra_params: na.rm
        finish_layer: function
        non_missing_aes: 
        optional_aes: 
        parameters: function
        required_aes: 
        retransform: TRUE
        setup_data: function
        setup_params: function
        super:  <ggproto object: Class Stat, gg>
    stat_params: list
    super:  <ggproto object: Class Layer, gg> 
 $ scales     :Classes 'ScalesList', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class ScalesList, gg>
    add: function
    clone: function
    find: function
    get_scales: function
    has_scale: function
    input: function
    n: function
    non_position_scales: function
    scales: list
    super:  <ggproto object: Class ScalesList, gg> 
 $ mapping    :List of 2
  ..$ x: language ~wt
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..$ y: language ~mpg
  .. ..- attr(*, ".Environment")=<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "uneval"
 $ theme      : list()
 $ coordinates:Classes 'CoordCartesian', 'Coord', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord, gg>
    aspect: function
    backtransform_range: function
    clip: on
    default: TRUE
    distance: function
    expand: TRUE
    is_free: function
    is_linear: function
    labels: function
    limits: list
    modify_scales: function
    range: function
    render_axis_h: function
    render_axis_v: function
    render_bg: function
    render_fg: function
    setup_data: function
    setup_layout: function
    setup_panel_guides: function
    setup_panel_params: function
    setup_params: function
    train_panel_guides: function
    transform: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class CoordCartesian, Coord, gg> 
 $ facet      :Classes 'FacetNull', 'Facet', 'ggproto', 'gg' <ggproto object: Class FacetNull, Facet, gg>
    compute_layout: function
    draw_back: function
    draw_front: function
    draw_labels: function
    draw_panels: function
    finish_data: function
    init_scales: function
    map_data: function
    params: list
    setup_data: function
    setup_params: function
    shrink: TRUE
    train_scales: function
    vars: function
    super:  <ggproto object: Class FacetNull, Facet, gg> 
 $ plot_env   :<environment: R_GlobalEnv> 
 $ labels     :List of 2
  ..$ x: chr "wt"
  ..$ y: chr "mpg"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "gg" "ggplot"
```

Comment: You are not looking at what you want to. You add annotation to p but do not store it back to p so p has no annotation :-). Try with p <- `p + annotate.....` and then `p$layers[[2]]$aes_params$label`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `ggplot_build`.

```r
p <- ggplot(mtcars[c(1,15),], aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  ## notice that I am adding this to `p`
  annotate("text", x = 4, y = 25, label = "Some text")
ggpb <- ggplot_build(p)
ggpb$data[[2]]
#   x  y PANEL group colour size angle hjust vjust alpha family fontface lineheight     label
# 1 4 25     1    -1  black 3.88     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2 Some text
```

The problem in your example is that you added the `annotate` to the plot for immediate rendering but did not store it in the `p` object.

Thanks @teunbrand, simpler with

```r
layer_data(p, 2)
#   x  y PANEL group colour size angle hjust vjust alpha family fontface lineheight     label
# 1 4 25     1    -1  black 3.88     0   0.5   0.5    NA               1        1.2 Some text
```

Comment: As a slightly more convenient function, you can use `layer_data(p, i = 2)` too, which essentially does the same thing.