# ggplot2 using scale_colour_manual access default colors?

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I am using `scale_colour_manual` to specify the possible colors I need. However, if I choose `red` I get the eye-burning red color rather than the milder ggplot2 default red that would appear if I didn't use `scale_colour_manual` in the first place. What are the labels or constants for accessing ggplot2 default color palette?

```
 ggplot(data=df, aes(x=n, y=rt, group=kernel, shape=kernel, colour=kernel)) + 
     geom_point(fill="white", size=3) + geom_line() + xlab("n") + ylab("Runtime (s)") + 
     opts(title=title,plot.title=theme_text(size=font.size)) + 
     scale_colour_manual(values=c("grey30", "red")) + 
     opts(legend.position = c(x_shift,0.87),legend.background=theme_rect(fill = "transparent",colour=NA))
```

Note that using 'red30' won't work, it only works for gray for some reason unknown to me.

Comment: Try "salmon" instead of "red".

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`red30` doesn't work, because there is no concept of having only thirty percent of a *color*, though there is the concept of having thirty percent of a shade of grey (i.e. 30% of the way between black and white.)

If you want a non eye-burning red with `scale_color_manual` you will need to specify colors in [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model), viz. by using three bytes to represent the red green and blue color in hexadecimal. Something like this should work

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=n, y=rt, group=kernel, shape=kernel, colour=kernel)) + 
 geom_point(fill="white", size=3) + geom_line() + xlab("n") + ylab("Runtime (s)") + 
 opts(title=title,plot.title=theme_text(size=font.size)) + 
 scale_colour_manual(values=c("grey30", "#EF8A62")) + 
 opts(legend.position = c(x_shift,0.87),legend.background=theme_rect(fill =  "transparent",colour=NA))
```

If you don't know about how to work with this sort of color coding refer to [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colors.asp). I don't know how to extract the colors ggplot uses programmatically, but you could always just load a plot you produced with the standard colors into some image editor (e.g. The Gimp) and find out what the exact color code is. You can find good color schemes on [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/), but note that `ggplot2` already has a function for those: [`scale_brewer`](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/scale_brewer.html).

Comment: to find the default ggplot colours, see the link in my comment above.

Comment: 'rgb' allows a transparency value.

Answer (score 4):

The default "pastel red" and "pastel blue" used in ggplot2 have hex codes of `#f8766d` and `#00b0f6`, respectively, and RGB codes `248,118,109` and `0,176,246`, respectively. To specify these with `scale_colour_manual`:

```
scale_colour_manual(values=c("#f8766d", "#00b0f6"))
```