# Change ggplot factor colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I notice that here [Box and whiskers plot](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_boxplot.html) the call:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(cyl)))
```

generates bright red/green/blue colors for boxplots fill, while:

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(vs)))
```

Generates a distinct pale green/red of colors. In my data, I get the second set of colors, but would like the first set (like in

```
p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(cyl)))
```

What controls which set of colors ggplot uses and how can you change it?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The default colours are evenly spaced hues around the colour wheel. You can check how this is generated from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette).

You can use `scale_fill_manual` with those colours:

```
p + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#F8766D", "#00BA38"))
```

Here, I used `ggplot_build(p)$data` from `cyl` to get the colors.

Alternatively, you can use another palette as well like so:

```
p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

And to find the colours in the palette, you can do:

```
require(RColorBrewer)
brewer.pal(9, "Set1")
```

Check the package for knowing the palettes and other options, if you're interested.

**Edit:** @user248237dfsf, as I *already* pointed out in the link at the top, this function from @Andrie shows the colors generated:

```
ggplotColours <- function(n=6, h=c(0, 360) +15){
  if ((diff(h)%%360) < 1) h[2] <- h[2] - 360/n
    hcl(h = (seq(h[1], h[2], length = n)), c = 100, l = 65)
}

> ggplotColours(2)
# [1] "#F8766D" "#00BFC4"

> ggplotColours(3)
# [1] "#F8766D" "#00BA38" "#619CFF"
```

If you look at the two colours generated, the first one is the same, but the second colour is not the same, when n=2 and n=3. This is because it generates colours of *evenly spaced* hues. If you want to use the colors for `cyl` for `vs` then you'll have to set `scale_fill_manual` and use these colours generated with n=3 from this function.

To verify that this is indeed what's happening you could do:

```
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
           geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(cyl)))

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) + 
           geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(vs)))
```

Now, if you do:

```
ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]]$fill
# [1] "#F8766D" "#00BA38" "#619CFF"

ggplot_build(p2)$data[[1]]$fill
# [1] "#F8766D" "#00BFC4" "#F8766D" "#00BFC4" "#F8766D"
```

You see that these are the colours that are generated using `ggplotColours` and the reason for the difference is also obvious. I hope this helps.

Comment: But that doesn't explain why for one variable plotted as a factor you get one set of colors and for different one you get another set of colors like in the doc page I linked to. The colors are evenly spaced, I can see that, but why is it different between the two? I want it to look like the first not the second.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to manually set the steps between each color on the hue wheel. That way we could get a greater contrast between consecutive factors. After 360 it should just continue from 0.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to previous answers:

When using the `col` aesthetic (instead of `fill`), use `scale_color_manual`. This is useful for `geom_point()`:

```
myColors <- c("#56ddc5", "#ff3db7", "#4699dd")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=hp, col=as.factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=myColors)
```

[image]

Comment: This method also works for geom_bar() when using scale_fill_manual().

Answer (score 0):

you can use these packages:

```
#install.packages(pals)
#install.packages(reshape2)
require(pals)
require(reshape2)
```

here you can find some sample dicrete palettes:

```
pal.bands(alphabet, alphabet2, cols25, glasbey, kelly, okabe, polychrome, 
stepped, stepped2, stepped3, tol, watlington,
        main="Discrete", show.names=FALSE)
```

and you can apply them like this:

```
 p +
   scale_fill_manual(values=as.vector(stepped3(20)))
```