# I need to change my ggplot colours to grey shades in r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code:

```
performance %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sexo, fill = factor(PLM.year1))) +
    geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

and its giving me some weird colours.. I want them in grey.. how can I change it, please?

Comment: You haven't done anything to assign the color scale you want. See the docs for any of the [`scale_fill_*`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html) functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [changing ggplot factor colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130497/changing-ggplot-factor-colors)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
+ scale_fill_grey(start=0.8, end=0.2)
```

based on the [ggplot2 documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_grey.html)

Comment: no worries, if the answer was helpful you an accept the proposed answer :)

Comment: it was, I did ;)