# How to change boxplot categories to unique colors using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, boxplot

Hi I'm a beginner and struggling to figure out how to make custom color changes to my boxplot using ggplot2? I would like to change females to a maroon color and males to a different shade of blue. [image: plot]

```
library(ggplot2)

    plot.x <- ggplot(doubleboxplot) + geom_boxplot(aes(sex, x))
    plot.y <- ggplot(doubleboxplot) + geom_boxplot(aes(sex, y))

    plot.x <- layer_data(plot.x)[,1:21]
    plot.y <- layer_data(plot.y)[,1:21]
    colnames(plot.x) <- paste0("x.", gsub("y", "", colnames(plot.x)))
    colnames(plot.y) <- paste0("y.", gsub("y", "", colnames(plot.y)))
    df <- cbind(plot.x, plot.y); rm(plot.x, plot.y)
    df$category <- sort(unique(doubleboxplot$sex))

    df

    library(dplyr)
    library(data.table)
    df.outliers <- df %>%
      select(category, x.middle, x.outliers, y.middle, y.outliers) %>%
      data.table::data.table()
    df.outliers <- df.outliers[, list(x.outliers = unlist(x.outliers), y.outliers = unlist(y.outliers)), 
                               by = list(category, x.middle, y.middle)]

    df.outliers

    p <- ggplot(df, aes(fill = category, color = category)) +

      # 2D box defined by the Q1 & Q3 values in each dimension, with outline
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = x.lower, xmax = x.upper, ymin = y.lower, ymax = y.upper), alpha = 0.3) +
      geom_rect(aes(xmin = x.lower, xmax = x.upper, ymin = y.lower, ymax = y.upper), 
                color = "black", fill = NA) +

      # whiskers for x-axis dimension with ends
      geom_segment(aes(x = x.min, y = y.middle, xend = x.max, yend = y.middle)) + #whiskers
      geom_segment(aes(x = x.min, y = y.lower, xend = x.min, yend = y.upper)) + #lower end
      geom_segment(aes(x = x.max, y = y.lower, xend = x.max, yend = y.upper)) + #upper end

      # whiskers for y-axis dimension with ends
      geom_segment(aes(x = x.middle, y = y.min, xend = x.middle, yend = y.max)) + #whiskers
      geom_segment(aes(x = x.lower, y = y.min, xend = x.upper, yend = y.min)) + #lower end
      geom_segment(aes(x = x.lower, y = y.max, xend = x.upper, yend = y.max)) + #upper end


      xlab("CD8 Activated") + ylab("CD8 CM") +
      coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0.5, 11.5), ylim = c(0.5, 11.5)) +
      theme_classic()


    p + geom_point(doubleboxplot, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = sex, color = sex), inherit.aes = F, alpha = 0.6)
```

Comment: See [`scale_color_manual()` and `scale_fill_manual()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [changing ggplot factor colors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15130497/changing-ggplot-factor-colors)

Comment: Also see this list of common ggplot2 colors

Answer (score 0):

Also see this list of common ggplot2 colors: http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour