# ggplot2: How to use same colors in different plots for same factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I pin the same color to a value in diffent plots?

Say I have two data.frames df1 and df2:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(c=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), x=1:5,  y=runif(5))
df2 <- data.frame(c=c('a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'h'), x=1:5,  y=runif(5))
```

When plotting them using c as color-indicator I get the same five colors.

```
g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

But I want that same values of c get the same color.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I now wrote a function which generates another function which computes the colors. I'm not sure if it's a good way. Comments appreciated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)

makeColors <- function(){
  maxColors <- 10
  usedColors <- c()
  possibleColors <- colorRampPalette( brewer.pal( 9 , "Set1" ) )(maxColors)

  function(values){
    newKeys <- setdiff(values, names(usedColors))
    newColors <- possibleColors[1:length(newKeys)]
    usedColors.new <-  c(usedColors, newColors)
    names(usedColors.new) <- c(names(usedColors), newKeys)
    usedColors <<- usedColors.new

    possibleColors <<- possibleColors[length(newKeys)+1:maxColors]
    usedColors
  }
} 

mkColor <- makeColors()


set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(c=c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'), x=1:5,  y=runif(5))
df2 <- data.frame(c=c('a', 'c', 'e', 'g', 'h'), x=1:5,  y=runif(5))

g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(values = mkColor(df1$c))
g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + scale_fill_manual(values = mkColor(df2$c))
grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

You can set your own fill scale using `scale_fill_manual`. I create a named vector with colors and different values of "c".

```
dd <- union(df1$c,df2$c)
dd.col <- rainbow(length(dd))
names(dd.col)  <- dd
```

Then :

```
g1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = dd.col)
g2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual("Legend", values = dd.col)
grid.arrange(g1, g2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: So I have to know how many different colors I will use. Is there a way to "collect" the colors during plotting each plot after another? My actual problem consists of many indepent plots and I don't know at the beginning how many (and what kind of) values for "c" I will get.

Comment: This can be combined with the method to get the default color palette in ggplot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette. E.g. `my_colors = gg_color_hue(length(my_factors))`, `names(my_colors) <- rev(my_factors)` and simply add `scale_color_manual(values = my_colors)` to each of your plots.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I ran this code, both legends contained all possible groups instead of only the groups present in each plot. Is there a way to include only the groups that are present in each plot in the legends?

Answer (score 8):

To make this kind of composite plots, `ggplot2` has facets:

```
df1$id = 'A'
df2$id = 'B'
df_all = rbind(df1, df2)
ggplot(df_all, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=c)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
    facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

When using facets, `ggplot2` treats both plots as one whole, keeping the color-value mapping the same.

Comment: Just in my example I put the two plots together. My real problem consists of many independent plots.