# Why do these two ggplots, generated the same way, order legends differently? How can I control it?

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, mds

I have a line of code that I am running on some data to make a MDS plot.  Lets start with the data first:

[Data for MDS 1](http://txt.do/dkwjx)

[Data for MDS 2](http://txt.do/dkwjj)

I am creating MDS plots using this line of code:

```
ggplot(mds, aes(X1,X2,color=Virus_Treatment,shape=Infection)) + geom_point(size=3) + ggtitle("MDS Plot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))
```

When I plot the data for MDS 1, it looks like this:[image: MDS plot 1]

When I plot the data for MDS 2, however, it looks like this: [image]

First issue:  Why is the infection legend on top for MDS 1, and on bottom for MDS 2?  I literally ran the same code on it, why is the legend changing it's behavior? I want consistency between these plots.  Is there any way to specify how legends are ordered?

Second Issue: I want the colors to be consistent for the Virus_Treatment part.   In MDS 2, there is 1 more type of data than in MDS 1, so that throws off the color consistency.  Is there a way to either re-order the data for MDS 2 so that the new color is at the end of the list, or to set a static color set manually?  I need to keep the colors the same across graphs, even if the number of colors being used is different.

Thanks in advance for any insight on this!

Comment: Color legends are determined based on the levels of the factor. Use `factor()` on `Virus_Treatment` in both data sets and specify the `levels` to be the complete list of unique values, in the order you want.

Comment: You can set colors via `scale_color_manual`; see, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068432/ggplot2-how-to-use-same-colors-in-different-plots-for-same-factor).  I remember that legend order can be [secret and unpredictable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11397958/2461552); see the "order" argument to `guide_legend` for controlling order.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gregor and aosmith for their answers.  This is what I've done to fix these issues:

```
Virus_Treatments <- factor(mds$Virus_Treatment, 
    levels = c("ACali09_contact", "AChkShng113_principal", 
               "AShng113_principal", "mock_mock", "ACali09_principal"))

color_set = c("#F8766D", "#7CAE00", "#00BFC4", "#C77CFF", "#FF61C3")

ggplot(mds, aes(X1,X2,color=Virus_Treatments,shape=Infection)) + geom_point(size=3) + ggtitle("MDS Plot") + theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold")) + guides(colour = guide_legend(order = 2), shape = guide_legend(order = 1)) + scale_colour_manual(values=color_set)
```