# How to plot a colour wheel by using ggplot?

Tags: r, graphics, colors, ggplot2

I'm reading the book *"ggplot2 - Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis" (Wickham, 2009)*, the section "Scaling" (page 32) says this:

> Scaling then involves mapping the data values to points in this space.
>   There are many ways to do this, but here since ***cyl*** is a categorical
>   variable we map values to evenly spaced hues on the colour wheel, as
>   shown in Figure 3.4. A different mapping is used when the variable is
>   continuous. The result of these conversions is Table 3.4, which
>   contains values that have meaning to the computer.

[image]

[image]

The book doesn't explain in detail how to get this table 3.4, much less figure 3.4. The built-in database is **mpg**. Anyone has an idea how to get this table and graph? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As for the table, it is an example of what is being done behind the scenes in translating between data space and aesthetic space. The table does not exist in that form anywhere, but `ggplot_build(qplot(displ, hwy, data=mpg, colour=factor(cyl)))$data[[1]]` is somewhat close (and is based on digging into how ggplot works).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Was wondering how to do this without `coord_polar()`, since the example from Wickham's book clearly does not. Turns out you can just use `geom_point(...)`.

```
library(ggplot2)
r  <- seq(0,1,length=201)
th <- seq(0,2*pi, length=201)
d  <- expand.grid(r=r,th=th)
gg <- with(d,data.frame(d,x=r*sin(th),y=r*cos(th),
                        z=hcl(h=360*th/(2*pi),c=100*r, l=65)))
ggplot(gg) +
  geom_point(aes(x,y, color=z), size=3)+
  scale_color_identity()+labs(x="",y="") +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

This renders in a few seconds. [This reference](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/) states that the default luminance, l=65.

Comment: Nicely done! And the data frame `gg` gives you the table of hexadecimal colors without any extra work. I tried your code with 501 x and y points and that smoothed out the edge of the circle and still ran pretty quickly.

Comment: Well done! **jlhoward**. But one doubt remains: is there any relationship between **factor(mpg$cyl)** and how this graph is obtained as mentioned in the book and showed in **Fig 3.4**?

Comment: Well, `factor(mpg$cyl)` has 4 levels, and the plot in Wickham's book shows 5 points on the color wheel, so no, I don't understand the connection. The response to the question I link to above shows how the colors are derived for a given number of levels though. This is just a graphical representation of that process.

Answer (score 10):

This is close to what you're looking for, but the color transitions might not be smooth enough. Hopefully someone else can improve upon this:

Code adapted from [here](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/colour).

```
# Create hsv grid
d = expand.grid(h=seq(0,1,0.01), s=seq(0,1,0.05), v=1)

p1 = ggplot() +
          coord_polar(theta="x") +
          scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL) +
          scale_y_continuous(breaks=NULL) +
          scale_fill_identity() +
          geom_rect(data=d, mapping=aes(xmin=h, xmax=h+resolution(h), 
                                        ymin=s, ymax=s+resolution(s), 
                                        fill=hsv(h,s,v)))
```

You can get smoother color transitions by using a finer grid for the `h` and `s` values, but it takes a long time to render the plot. You can change the brightness by setting the value of `v` between zero and 1. (Per @BrodieG's comment, set v=1/2 to get the brightness level of the figure in Hadley's ggplot2 book.)

Below is a version of the plot using a step-size of 0.001 for the `h` values (while keeping the `s` step-size at 0.05). This took a couple of minutes to render on my relatively new Macbook Pro, but the transitions are pretty smooth along the `h` coordinate:

```
png("Colour wheel.png", 2000, 2000) 
p1
dev.off()
```

[image]

To get a table of colors, you can use the `hsv()` function, which returns hexadecimal color values. For example:

```
# Make up some hsv colors
colors = data.frame(h=seq(0.1,0.5,length.out=6), 
                    s=seq(0.5,0.9,length.out=6), 
                    v=c(.5,.5,.5,.9,.9,.9))

# Convert to hexadecimal
apply(colors, 1, function(x) hsv(x[1],x[2],x[3]))
[1] "#806640" "#7A8036" "#50802B" "#3CE642" "#29E68B" "#17E6E6"

# Plot them to see what they look like
plot(1:6,rep(1,6), pch=15, cex=5, col=apply(colors, 1, function(x) hsv(x[1],x[2],x[3])))
```

Comment: +1.  I think you need to use a constant V value at 1/2 max brightness to replicate the image.