# what is default color of smooth curve in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make my report using only two colors. I would like to know what's the default color of smooth curve in ggplot2 called so I can name my bar/line/pie accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Option 1: use ggplot-default colours. Option 2: use your own set of colours everywhere, including ggplot

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25211125/1655567) the `ggplot_build()` function can do precisely what you want.

Comment: The blue used in the geom_smooth line does not appear to be the same as those generated by the default color palette formula 'equally spaced hues around the color wheel, starting from 15'. @Ben Bolker's answer below is the only place I've found an answer to this specific and distinct question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following @Konrad's comment pointing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211125/1655567):

```
library("ggplot2")
dd <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)
g1 <- ggplot(dd,aes(x,y))+geom_smooth()
unique(ggplot_build(g1)$data[[1]]$colour)  ## "#3366FF"
plot(1,1,cex=8,pch=16,col="#3366FF")
```

[image]

This is not actually an exact duplicate of [emulate ggplot colour palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette): if we build a three-category coloured plot plus a smooth we get:

```
sapply(ggplot_build(g1)$data,function(x) unique(x$colour))
## [[1]]
## [1] "#F8766D" "#00BA38" "#619CFF" # three colours from colour wheel 
## [[2]]
## [1] "#3366FF"    # geom_smooth colour
```