# Easiest way of editing labels in legend when using color and shape in aes

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I wonder if there is a function like:

```
scale_color_hue()
```

but for shapes.
Editing the labels of a legend when using colors in aes is esay with that function, but I cannot do it when mixing colors and shapes.

For instance, the command:

```
ggplot(subdata, aes(x=factor(rGPUs), y=Speedup, colour=factor(Factor), shape=factor(Factor), group=Factor, ymin=0)) +
  geom_line(size=1) + geom_point(size=4) +  
  scale_color_hue(labels = c("1X", "1.5X", "2X"))
```

generates this chart: [image]

I would like to plot it without the second legend. Nevertheless, I would not like to use the functions:

```
scale_color_manual()
scale_shape_manual()
```

since they need the labels together with the values, such as it is done in:

- [Editing legend (text) labels in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635662/editing-legend-text-labels-in-ggplot)
- [R manually set shape by factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218002/r-manually-set-shape-by-factor)

among many others.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something obvious, but what's wrong with simply adding `scale_shape_discrete(labels = c("1X", "1.5X", "2X"))`? You don't need to specify the values, just labels.

Comment: You were right! I was looking for something like scale_shape_hue() and I didn't think of your solution. Thank you!