# ggplot and the geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am new to R and `ggplot2`.I have searched a lot regarding this but I could not find the solution.

```
Sample  observation1    observation2    observation3    percentage
sample1_A   163453473   131232689   61984186    30.6236955883
Sample1_B   170151351   137202212   59242536    26.8866816109
sample2_A   194102849   162112484   89158170    40.4183031852
sample2_B   170642240   141888123   79925652    41.7493687378
sample3_A   192858504   161227348   90532447    41.8068248626
sample3_B   177174787   147412720   81523935    40.5463120438
sample4_A   199232380   174656081   118115358   55.6409038531
sample4_B   211128931   186848929   123552556   54.7201927527
sample5_A   186039420   152618196   87012356    40.9656544833
sample5_B   145855252   118225865   66265976    39.5744515254
sample6_A   211165202   186625116   112710053   48.5457722338
sample6_B   220522502   193191927   114882014   47.238670909
```

I am planning to plot a bar plot with `ggplot2`. I want to plot the first three columns as a bar plot "dodge" and label the `observation3` bar with the percentage. I could plot the bars as below but I could not use `geom_text()` to add the label.

```
data1 <- read.table("readStats.txt", header=T)
data1.long <- melt(data1)
ggplot(data1.long[1:36,], aes(data1.long$Sample[1:36],y=data1.long$value[1:36], fill=data1.long$variable[1:36])) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5, position="dodge")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform `data1` to long form with the observation columns as the measure variables and the `Sample` and `percentage` columns as the id variables.  Compute the maximum value, `mx`, to be used to place the percentages.  Then perform the plot.  Note that `geom_bar` uses `data1.long` but `geom_text` uses `data1`.  **We have colored the text giving the percentages the same color as the `observation3` bars.** (See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette) for how to specify default colors.) Both inherit `aes(x = Sample)` but use different `y` and other aesthetics.  We clean up the X axis labels by removing all lower case letters and underscores from the `data1$Sample` (optional).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data1.long <- melt(data1, measure = 2:4)  # cols 2:4 are observation1, ..., observation3
mx <- max(data1.long$value)  # maximum observation value
ggplot(data1.long, aes(x = Sample, y = value)) +
   geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity", width = 0.5, position = "dodge") + 
   geom_text(aes(y = mx, label = paste0(round(percentage), "%")), data = data1, 
        col = "#619CFF", vjust = -0.5) +
   scale_x_discrete(labels = gsub("[a-z_]", "", data1$Sample))
```

(click on chart to enlarge)

[image: screenshot]

**Note:**  We used this data.  Note that one occurrence of Sample was changed to sample with a lower case s:

```
Lines <- "Sample  observation1    observation2    observation3    percentage
sample1_A   163453473   131232689   61984186    30.6236955883
sample1_B   170151351   137202212   59242536    26.8866816109
sample2_A   194102849   162112484   89158170    40.4183031852
sample2_B   170642240   141888123   79925652    41.7493687378
sample3_A   192858504   161227348   90532447    41.8068248626
sample3_B   177174787   147412720   81523935    40.5463120438
sample4_A   199232380   174656081   118115358   55.6409038531
sample4_B   211128931   186848929   123552556   54.7201927527
sample5_A   186039420   152618196   87012356    40.9656544833
sample5_B   145855252   118225865   66265976    39.5744515254
sample6_A   211165202   186625116   112710053   48.5457722338
sample6_B   220522502   193191927   114882014   47.238670909"

data1 <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

**UPDATE:**  minor improvements

Answer (score 0):

It might be that [G. Grothendieck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33963406/1305688) is a better solution, but here's my suggestion (code below)

[image]

```
# install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies = TRUE)
require(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(Sample = structure(1:12, .Label = c("sample1_A", 
"Sample1_B", "sample2_A", "sample2_B", "sample3_A", "sample3_B", 
"sample4_A", "sample4_B", "sample5_A", "sample5_B", "sample6_A", 
"sample6_B"), class = "factor"), observation1 = c(163453473L, 
170151351L, 194102849L, 170642240L, 192858504L, 177174787L, 199232380L, 
211128931L, 186039420L, 145855252L, 211165202L, 220522502L), 
    observation2 = c(131232689L, 137202212L, 162112484L, 141888123L, 
    161227348L, 147412720L, 174656081L, 186848929L, 152618196L, 
    118225865L, 186625116L, 193191927L), observation3 = c(61984186L, 
    59242536L, 89158170L, 79925652L, 90532447L, 81523935L, 118115358L, 
    123552556L, 87012356L, 66265976L, 112710053L, 114882014L), 
    percentage = c(30.6236955883, 26.8866816109, 40.4183031852, 
    41.7493687378, 41.8068248626, 40.5463120438, 55.6409038531, 
    54.7201927527, 40.9656544833, 39.5744515254, 48.5457722338, 
    47.238670909)), .Names = c("Sample", "observation1", "observation2", 
"observation3", "percentage"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

# install.packages("reshape2", dependencies = TRUE)
require(reshape2)

    data1.long <- melt(df, id=c("Sample"), measure.var = c("observation1", "observation2", "observation3"))


data1.long$percentage <- paste(round(data1.long$percentage, 2), "%", sep="")
data1.long[data1.long$variable == "observation1" | data1.long$variable == "observation2" ,2] <- ""

ggplot(data1.long, aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill=variable)) + 
       geom_bar(, stat="identity", width=0.5, position="dodge") + 
       geom_text(aes(label = percentage), vjust=2.10, size=2, hjust=-.06, angle = 90)
```