# Choose color ggraph R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I try to plot a bipartite network with the edges of the same color than one of their nodes.
For example, let's take an movie/actor bipartite graph as an exemple, with 7 movies and 15 actors, and each actor has a nationality. 
I want to have the edge between an actor and a movie of the same color than the nationality of the actor.

```
NG1 <- 7
NG2 <- 15
Nat <- sample(x = c("French", "English", "Italian", "American", "Chinese"), size = NG2, replace = T)
G <- graph.empty(NG1+NG2)
```

[Here, `head(Nat)` returns `"Italian"  "English"  "American" "French"   "French"   "French"`]
The code to create the edgelist:

```
E1 <- sample(x=1:NG1, size = 30, replace = T)
E2 <- sample(x=(NG1+1):(NG1+NG2), size = 30, replace = T)
EL <- c(rbind(E1, E2))
G <- add_edges(G, EL, nat = Nat[E2-NG1])
```

[Here, `head(EL)` returns `1 14  3 13  2 15`]
The different aes arguments:

```
GROUP <- c(rep("Movie", NG1), rep("Act", NG2))
COL <- c(rep("Movie", NG1), Nat)
TXT <- c(as.character(1:NG1), letters[1:NG2])
```

And now the ggraph instructions:

```
 ggraph(G, layout = 'kk') + 
      geom_node_point(aes(col = COL, shape = GROUP, size = 7)) + 
      geom_edge_link(aes(col = nat)) +
      geom_node_text(aes(label = TXT), size = 4)
```

[image: Plot]

As you can see in the bottom, actor a, which is Italien has a blue node, but is connected with a pink edge with movie 7... How can I specify the color palette for nodes (here 6 colors) and edges (the 5 first colors of the nodes)?

I hope that I have made clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After two hours, I finally found a solution !

I used the function `gg_color_hue` defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette) to emulate the 6 colors used for the nodes and then:

```
+ scale_edge_colour_manual(values = cols[1:5])
```