# igraph - set node color to categorical vertex attribute

Tags: r, igraph

I have network g.8 of 24 nodes, and i have set a vertex attribute "country" to for the nodes. I'm trying to set the vertex colors to match the vertex attribute country (n = 10), but the network comes out where nodes have no colour. I get the right colour for the legend though.

EDIT: I have managed to get the nodes coloured, but they don't match the colours on the legend at all.

The data looks like this:

> nodes  Id                     Label                  Country
>   Degree                                        
>     1 Urabenos               Urabenos               Colombia
>   4  2 Sinaloa Cartel         Sinaloa Cartel         Mexico
>   16  3 Los Zetas              Los Zetas              Mexico
>   8  4 Norte del Valle Cartel Norte del Valle Cartel Colombia
>   2  5 Cosa Nostra            Cosa Nostra            Italy
>   4  6 NDrangheta             NDrangheta             Italy
>   8  7 14K                    14K                    China
>   6  8 Chinese Triads         Chinese Triads         China
>   2  9 Sun yee on             Sun yee on             China
>   4 10 MS-13                  MS-13                  United States
>   4
>
> ## … with 14 more rows
>
> **edges**  Source                      Target            Type       Label                                                 
>                                 1 14K
>   Sinaloa Cartel    Undirected Drug Trafficking             2 14K
>   Sun yee on        Undirected Drug trafficking             3 14K
>   Wo Shing Wo       Undirected Unspecified                  4
>   Beltran-Leyva Cartel        The Juarez Cartel Undirected New Edge -
>   Association       5 Beltran-Leyva Cartel        Los Zetas
>   Undirected New Edge - Association       6 Bonnano Family
>   NDrangheta        Undirected New Edge - Drug Trafficking  7
>   Clerkenwell Crime Syndicate Russian Mafia     Undirected New Edge -
>   Association       8 Cosa Nostra                 Sinaloa Cartel
>   Undirected Drug Trafficking             9 Cosa Nostra
>   NDrangheta        Undirected New Edge - Association      10 First
>   Capital Command       Tahvili Group     Undirected New Edge - Drug
>   Trafficking
>
> **graph**
>   + attr: name (v/c), Label (v/c), Country (v/c), Degree (v/n), Type (e/c), Label (e/c)
>   + edges from 9f46a4b (vertex names):  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq1gK.png) Sinaloa Cartel       --14K                          [2] 14K                  --Sun yee on                   [3] 14K
>   --Wo Shing Wo                  [4] Beltran-Leyva Cartel --The Juarez Cartel            [5] Los Zetas            --Beltran-Leyva Cartel
>   [6] NDrangheta           --Bonnano Family               [7] Russian
>   Mafia        --Clerkenwell Crime Syndicate  [8] Sinaloa Cartel
>   --Cosa Nostra
>   + ... omitted several edges

My Code so far:

```
g.8 <- graph_from_data_frame(d=edges.8, vertices=nodes.8, 
    directed=FALSE)


par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))

plot(g.8)

set_vertex_attr(g.8, "country", index = V(g.8), 
as.character(nodes.8$Country))
colrs <- brewer.pal(10, "Set3")
V(g.8)$color <- colrs[V(g.8)$Country]
plot(g.8, vertex.color=colrs,
vertex.label.cex = .75,
edge.label = edges.8$Label,
edge.label.cex = .5,
edge.label.color = "darkgrey") 


 #plot legend for node colors
     legend("topright", c("Brazil","Canada", "China", "Colombia", 
     "Italy", "Japan", "Mexico", "Russia", "UK", "US"), 
     pch=21,col="#777777", pt.bg=colrs, pt.cex=2, cex=.6, bty="n", 
      ncol=1,)
```

EDIT:

Changed the code according to the great advice given. The color map works, but the vertex colors are still random.

```
# create a color map
col <- data.frame(Country = unique(nodes.8$Country), 
stringsAsFactors = F)
col$color <- brewer.pal(nrow(col), "Set3")
col

# attach the colors to the nodes data.frame
nodes.8$color <- col$color[match(nodes.8$Country, col$Country)]
nodes.8$color <- col$color[match(nodes.8$Country, col$Country)]

# igraph object
g.8 <- graph_from_data_frame(edges.8,
                       vertices=nodes.8, 
                       directed=FALSE)


plot(g.8,
     vertex.label.cex = .75,
     edge.label.cex = .5,
     edge.label.color = "darkgrey",
     vertex.color = col$color) 
     legend("topright", legend = col$Country, pt.bg=col$color, 
     bty="n",
       pch=21, col="#777777")
```

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596647/match-vertex-and-edge-color-in-igraph/61598316#61598316

Comment: also, it would be great if you could share your data using ```dput``` so that your example is reproducible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I'll have a look, thank you!

Comment: Hi @desval I tried to share the data, but didn't work. But I've made edits to my post, with more details and glimpse of what the data looks like. I got colours to my nodes, but they don't match the legend, or the column in the data.frame.

Comment: I am pretty sure that is not the output of dput, for the next questions maybe try to follow the guidelines in the link ;)

Comment: @desval sorry about that, I'm brand new to stackoverflow, trying to learn!

Comment: You should leave out ````vertex.color = col$color````, because it is already in the nodes data.frame and therefore in the igraph object. Plot uses by default the attribute color of the nodes data. For sharing the data, if it isnt too big, just paste the output of ````dput(nodes.8)```` into your questions. Same thing for the edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possibility is to create a map within unique values of the variable Country and the colors you want to use. You can use this map to add colors to the data.frame before you create the i.graph object, so that colors are displayed by default. Then you can use this map for the legend:

```
library(igraph)
library(RColorBrewer)

# create a color map
col <- data.frame(Country = unique(nodes$Country), stringsAsFactors = F)
col$color <- brewer.pal(nrow(col), "Set3")

# attach the colors to the nodes data.frame
nodes$color <- col$color[match(nodes$Country, col$Country)]

# igraph object
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edges,
                           vertices=nodes, 
                             directed=FALSE)

# check attributes
# each node has a color, which matches the country, it will be used by plot
vertex_attr(g)
$name
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

$Label
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

$Country
 [1] "Italy" "Italy" "Italy" "US"    "Italy" "US"    "US"    "US"    "Italy" "China"

$color
 [1] "#8DD3C7" "#8DD3C7" "#8DD3C7" "#FFFFB3" "#8DD3C7" "#FFFFB3" "#FFFFB3" "#FFFFB3" "#8DD3C7" "#BEBADA"


# plot
plot(g,
   # vertex.color = V(g)$color, # this is added by default, no need to include it
     vertex.label.cex = .75,
     edge.label.cex = .5,
     edge.label.color = "darkgrey") 
legend("topright", legend = col$Country, pt.bg=col$color, bty="n",
       pch=21, col="#777777")
```

[image]

Data

```
set.seed(123)
nodes <- data.frame(Id = letters[1:10],
                    Label = letters[1:10],
                    Country = sample(c("China", "US", "Italy"), 10, replace = T))

edges <- data.frame(t(combn(letters[1:10], 2, simplify = T)))
names(edges) <- c("Source","Target")
edges <- edges[sample(1:nrow(edges), 25),]
```

Comment: Hi @desval thank you! I tried your suggested code, and the produced color map works, and is correct. But for some reason the color of the nodes are still random, and don't correspond to the data.

I'll add an edit with the new code and output.

Comment: in your code you write over the right colors! Either drop ````vertex.color = col$color```` or use ````vertex.color = V(g)$color ````