# User Specific colors while plotting random number of elements

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I want to plot a vector in R with different colors. I write:

```
    x <- 1:10
    plot(x,col=x)
```

or,

```
    x <- 1:5
    plot(x,col=x)
```

From the plot see that in both the cases "red" is the second color which R chooses, black being the first. I want to make "red" the first.

Please note that defining 5 or 10 colors is not the solution since 5 and 10 are arbitrary numbers.

Any help would be helpful.

My original problem was defining user specific colors in ggplot2 using:

```
    aes(color=factor(Variable))
```

In this I wanted to make red the first color.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems here.

When you plot using base R, colours are chosen from the default palette:

```
palette()
[1] "black"   "red"     "green3"  "blue"    "cyan"    "magenta" "yellow"  "gray"
```

Now you see why black is first and red is second. In your example, to get red first you might try:

```
plot(1:5, col = 2:6)
```

but really, neither that plot nor the colour scheme make a lot of sense.

Now to `ggplot2`: it uses its own colour palette [as described in these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette). If you want to colour by a factor variable and override that palette, you might use `scale_color_brewer()` with a defined palette *e.g.*:

```
+ scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

or to use your own colours, `scale_color_manual()`, *e.g.* for the first colour to be red:

```
+ scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", ...)
```