# Always use the same fill colors barplot ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, fill, geom-bar

For different products I am trying to plot the sales per saleschannel in a stacked barplot using ggplot in R. I plotted the products on the x-axis and  the amounts plotted on the y-axis. The fill is the channels.

My code looks like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=products, y=sales, fill=channel)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

There are a total of 4 different saleschannels (website, email, street sales, direct message). The problem I face is that for different products different plot colors are used, because not all products have used each saleschannel for sales. Important to know is that I want to plot each product in a separate plot. For example, product1 has used all four saleeschannels and will thus use four different colors in the stacked barplot. However, product2 only used three saleschannels (website, email and street sales), and will thus use three different colors in the stacked barplot. Because of this, R uses different colors for the products for plots with products that use four channels.

Is there a way that I can always use the same colors no matter how many saleschannels a product uses?

edit: I added the code as was requested, see below:

```
products <- c("product1","product1","product1","product1","product1","product1","product1",
          "product2","product2","product2","product2","product2","product2",
          "product3","product3","product3","product3","product3","product3","product3",
          "product4","product4","product4","product4","product4","product4","product4","product4")

sales <- c(5,12,14,21,8,9,11,2,5,6,8,19,21,13,14,5,22,19,17,13,12,10,8,6,9,11,15,16)
saleschannel <- c("website","website","website","email","street sales","direct message","direct message",
              "website","website","email","email","street sales","street sales",
              "website","website","email","email","street sales","street sales","direct message",
              "website","website","email","email","street sales","street sales","direct message","direct message")

df <- data.frame(products, sales, saleschannel)
df_1 <- subset(df, products=="product1")
df_2 <- subset(df, products=="product2")

plot_product1 <- ggplot(df_1, aes(x=products, y=sales, fill=saleschannel)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

plot_product2 <- ggplot(df_2, aes(x=products, y=sales, fill=saleschannel)) +  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plot_product1, plot_product2)
```

This gets me the following plots:

[image: as per data and code getting this plot]

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data and the code you're working on so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Hi! I added the code as you requested, see the original post. I hope you can help me.

Comment: just now i am added the plot as per the code and what u want to achieve as output?

Comment: I would like the colors that are used for the channels to be always the same. As you can see now in the attached image, the color for "street sales" is different in plot 1 and plot 2, I would like R to always use the same color for a channel, no matter how many channels a product uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scale_fill_manual(values = ...)`, together with preset colors for each saleschannel.

First, you need to get the explicit names of the colors. You can use any other colors you like, for example the packages `RColorBrewer` has some options. Here, I use the ggplot2 default, like shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197703/082472):

```
# n: number of colors to generate
gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
  hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
  hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
}
```

Next, define a color for each sales channel by creating a named string vector, where the names are the `saleschannel` levels and the values are the colors:

```
s = unique(saleschannel)
cols = setNames(gg_color_hue(length(s)), s)
cols
##       website          email   street sales direct message 
##     "#F8766D"      "#7CAE00"      "#00BFC4"      "#C77CFF"
```

Add explicit color scales to your plots. In your case, the aestetic of choice is `fill`, therefore you need `scale_fill_manual`. You can also add `+ scale_fill_manual(...)` to the end of your definitions of `plot_productX`:

```
plot_product1 <- plot_product1 + scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
plot_product2 <- plot_product2 + scale_fill_manual(values = cols)
```

Then use `plot_grid` (an alternative is `gridExtra::grid.arrange`) as in your question

[image: plots with same color scale]

Comment: This works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Hugovanp Great :) However, this answer assumes that you don't want a plot like in  sai saran's answer. If you do, their solution is simpler. Also, there is [faceting](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/), which also synchronizes the axis scales

Answer (score 1):

Can u try this code :

```
library(dplyr)
df1<-df%>%filter(products %in% c( "product1" ,"product2")) 

ggplot(df1,aes(x=products,y=sales,fill=saleschannel))+geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: updated one]

Comment: This works if you want to plot it in a single plot, however, I want it in separate plots. I already have the solution (see answer akraf above). Thanks for your suggestion!