# Assign color in ggplot aes to the color parameter of stat_function

Tags: r, ggplot2

Lets say I want to create a histogram with color aes and I have several functions fitted for each of the factor-levels of the column that I use for the color aes.

Sorry for the complicated description, here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(1234)
wdata = data.frame(
  sex = factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight = c(rnorm(200, 55), rnorm(200, 58)))
head(wdata)

fun_f <- function(x){dnorm(x, mean = 55)}
fun_m <- function(x){dnorm(x, mean = 58)}

p <- ggplot(wdata, aes(x = weight, color=sex, fill = sex)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(color = sex),position = "dodge", bins = 30)+
  stat_function(fun=function(x){ 
    fun_m(x)*60
  }, 
  geom="line",
  color ="blue",
  size = 1)+

  stat_function(fun=function(x){ 
    fun_f(x)*60
  },
  color ="red",
  geom="line",
  size = 1)

p
```

My goal now is to use the color for `wdata[sex=="f"]` for `fun_f` instead of `color="red"`. Analogously for `fun_m`.

Is that possible?

Comment: You can find default colors e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_function` takes an `aes` mapping just like any other `ggplot` layer, so it will actually inherit the `color = sex, fill = sex` that you set initially.

However, to get `stat_function` to recognize the different values for `sex` that are in the data, you can filter in the `data` argument. If you think about it, your function is independent of the actual data, so there otherwise isn't anything happening to say one curve should be drawn for `"M"` and one for `"F"` until you trigger it manually. Then set the colors you want in both the color and fill scales.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(wdata, aes(x = weight, color = sex, fill = sex)) +
  geom_histogram(position = "dodge") +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) fun_m(x) * 60, data = . %>% filter(sex == "M")) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) fun_f(x) * 60, data = . %>% filter(sex == "F")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("F" = "red", "M" = "blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("F" = "red", "M" = "blue"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-02-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>