# Generate a ggplot2 palette in javascript

Tags: javascript, ggplot2

The ggplot2 color palette is very common in data visualization, but how can we get a similar palette generated on the web?

At this point, i would consider just manually generating some palettes using R code, and copying the resulting hex codes to a data array in JS, but having an accurate formula for the coloring would be interesting

I am trying the built-in LCH (light chroma hue) support in CSS, but the spectrum that the CSS LCH has seems to just not match what R has. I also tried `oklch` and it is a bit better, but still doesn't match

reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/hue

```js
// tested and this matches R version of seq
// reproduced from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197559/emulate-ggplot2-default-color-palette
function seq(start, end, n) {
  return Array.from(
    { length: n + 1 },
    (_, i) => start + (i * (end - start)) / n
  );
}
function gg_color_hue(n) {
  const hues = seq(50, 410, n);
  return hues.map((h) => `lch(65% 100% ${h})`).slice(0, n);
}

function ColRow({ n }) {
  const cols = gg_color_hue(n);
  return (
    <div>
      {cols.map((c) => (
        <div
          style={{
            display: "inline-block",
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            background: c,
          }}
        ></div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ColRow n={2} />
      <ColRow n={3} />
      <ColRow n={4} />
      <ColRow n={5} />
      <ColRow n={6} />
    </>
  );
}
```

color palette generated by the JS code

[image: lch palette from js]

color palette generated by the JS code if lch is replaced with oklch

[image: oklch palette from js]

color palettes generated by R code

[image: R palette]

code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/funny-archimedes-jj6h77?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A1%2C1-64%2C1